# get HTTP error 416 when use dojo with jsonrest to render to FilteringSelect

Tags: dojo, store

I am fresh on Dojo and now trying to use dojo/store/JsonRest to render to FilteringSelect widget, but dunno why get 416(Requested Range Not Satisfiable) and the error message is dijit.form.FilteringSelect RequestError:

```
Unable to load http://localhost:8080/DojoTutorial/DojoLabs/06-DijitsAndStores/06/data.json?value=* status: 416
```

**06TestPage.html**

```
<script
type="text/javascript"
data-dojo-config="'parseOnLoad': false, 'async': true"
src="../../Shared/dojo18/dojo/dojo.js"          
></script>

<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="06Test.js"
></script>
</head>

<body class="claro">
    <div id="selectBox"></div>
</body>
```

**06/data.json**

```
[ { id: "ENG", value: "England" },
{ id: "SCOT", value: "Scotland" },
{ id: "WAL", value: "Wales" },
{ id: "NI", value: "Northern Ireland" }]
```

**06Test.js**

```
require(["dojo/store/JsonRest",
         "dijit/form/FilteringSelect",
         "dojo/parser",
         "dojo/domReady!"
         ], 
function(JsonRest, FilteringSelect, parser){ 
    var theApp = function(){
         var myStore = new JsonRest({target: "06/data.json", idProperty: "id"});
         var storeList = new FilteringSelect({store:myStore, searchAttr: "value"}, "selectBox");
    };

    parser.parse().then(theApp);
});
```

Comment: is your Server equipped to serve **REST** request from the client? Your server should be capable of handling **REST** services in order to use the **JSONRest** module.

Comment: How to know if my server equipped to serve REST request? I am using Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost

Answer (score 0):

The JsonRest store will put a `Range` header in the requests to the server. If you look in Firebug (or your dev tools) when the FilteringSelect shows the dropdown, you should see a GET request to 06/data.json with a header like this:

```
Range: items=x-y
```

Your server is responsible for handling this, and only return the appropriate items.

I've noticed that Dojo sometimes send a header that is missing the second value (the `y` above). So the header sent to the server is:

```
Range: items=0-
```

I don't know if this is technically a valid Range header, but it happens.

When you create the FilteringSelect, you can set a pageSize, and this seems to ensure that a full Range header is sent.

```
var storeList = new FilteringSelect({
        store:myStore, 
        pageSize: 150, 
        searchAttr: "value"
    }, "selectBox");
```

Since you don't really want "paging" in your FilteringSelect (you just want all items), just set the pageSize to something that you know for sure will be enough for all the items. (And of course, in your case you just have a static file, not a REST server, so the Range header doesn't really matter anyway.)

Comment: I already tried what you said by adding pageSize: 955, but still got the same error result. How can I know how many pageSize should I set?

Comment: @labnattoise It doesn't really matter, since you are just requesting a static file (in other words, there is no code that filters or limits the items on the server, it's just a regular file). Tomcat really shouldn't care about the Range header at all, but for some reason it does. I wonder if it sees the .json file type and handles it specially. Does anything change if you rename the file to something like `06/data.json.txt` ?

Comment: If I change the .json like 06/data.json.txt, I get another error msg:
GET http://localhost:8080/DojoTutorial/DojoEnablement/06-DijitsAndStores/06/data.json?value=* 404 (Not Found)

Comment: If Tomcat doesn't care about the Range header, what's wrong for it?

Comment: @labnattoise Sorry, should have mentioned that when you change the file name to .txt, you also have to change your code, of course! Namely the line with `new JsonRest(..` to match the new filename. Note that this is just a test to check if Tomcat actually tries to be clever because of the .json extension. You will probably get better answers if you ask in the Tomcat section of Stackoverflow though :)